# Excel crashing after changing cell colors

Tags: excel, vba

We have a file that we use around the office. It's made by someone who is not working here anymore.

For a while, the file keeps crashing when we change any cell color.
There are some macro's in the file and I know a bit of VBA myself but I cannot find any problems.

I was hoping someone here could help me.
All the macros are called via buttons and when I remove all the code in the module then I can change the cell color.

So is the module corrupted or is there something wrong with the code, any ideas?

The code is not tidy at all, my apologies for that.

This is the code:

```
Sub Info()

MsgBox "Grijze cellen bevatten formules -> bij voorkeur niet wijzigen" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Per regel wordt één ruimte ingevoerd, de kolom 'aantal' wordt alleen bij totalen meegenomen"     & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Let op met standaard plakken omdat ook de voorwaardelijke opmaak (lijsten) worden     gekopieerd" & vbCr & _
        "    Gebruik liever 'waarden plakken' als kopieren noodzakelijk is" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Geen regels invoegen, gebruik de kopieerknoppen bovenin" & vbCr & _
        "Regels in zijn geheel verwijderen (rechts klikken op het regelnummer)" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Maximale waarde van bouwbesluit en eigen invoer wordt gehanteerd" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Overstort: " & vbCr & _
        "- Invullen niet noodzakelijk" & vbCr & _
        "- Dient bij beide ruimtes te worden ingevuld" & vbCr & _
        "- vb. de overstort van gang naar badkamer dient te worden ingevuld als afvoer van de gang EN     toevoer in de badkamer" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Mogelijke foutmelding over kringverwijzingen bij openen negeren" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Standaard verdiepingshoogte controleren wanneer regel wordt ingevoegd" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Het OVB-blad filtert automatisch op het streepje in de kolom 'Voldoet'," & vbCr & _
        "wanneer je een ruimte toch in het OVB-blad wilt laten zien dient het" & vbCr & _
        "streepje vervangen te worden", vbInformation, "INSTRUCTIES"
        
End Sub


Sub knopwoningbouw()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("3002").Copy
Rows("1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("2").Delete

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("1").Hidden = False

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("10").Hidden = True

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("11").Hidden = False

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("38").Hidden = True

Sheets("Sjabloon").Rows("81:97").Copy
Rows("39").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = True
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("G:H").Hidden = True
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("J:M").Hidden = True
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("O").Hidden = True
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("Y").Hidden = True
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AF:AI").Hidden = True
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AK:DE").Hidden = True

Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 20
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("N").ColumnWidth = 17
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("Q").ColumnWidth = 8.57
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("R").ColumnWidth = 18
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AD").ColumnWidth = 8.43
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AE").ColumnWidth = 20
Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AJ").ColumnWidth = 8

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("3017:3019").Delete


End Sub


Sub knoputiliteitsbouw()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("3").RowHeight = 20

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("3000").Copy
Rows("1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("2").Delete

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("1").Hidden = False

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("10").Hidden = True

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("11:38").Hidden = False

Sheets("Sjabloon").Rows("63:79").Copy
Rows("39").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = True
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Sheets("Algemeen").Rows("3017:3019").Delete

Sheets("Algemeen").Columns("AL").Hidden = True

End Sub

Sub woningb()

Answer = MsgBox("Verdieping wordt boven de geselecteerde cel ingevoegd." & vbCr & _
            "(Dus ook als dit midden in een andere verdieping is)" & vbCr & vbCr & _
            "Wilt u doorgaan?", vbYesNo, "LET OP!")

If Answer = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Invoegen verdieping beëindigd", vbCritical, "Invoegen beëindigd"
    Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Sjabloon").Rows("81:97").Copy
Rows(Selection.Row).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Calculate

End Sub

Sub utiliteitsb()

Answer = MsgBox("Verdieping wordt boven de geselecteerde cel ingevoegd." & vbCr & _
            "(Dus ook als dit midden in een andere verdieping is)" & vbCr & vbCr & _
            "Wilt u doorgaan?", vbYesNo, "LET OP!")

If Answer = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Invoegen verdieping beëindigd", vbCritical, "Invoegen beëindigd"
    Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Sjabloon").Rows("63:79").Copy
Rows(Selection.Row).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub


Sub ovbutiliteitsbouw()
'
'   Macro kopieert voor OVB UTILITEITSBOUW relevante informatie naar een nieuw blad
'   RPR, 03/2012

Answer = MsgBox("Door deze handeling wordt het huidige blad ovb utiliteitsbouw verwijderd (indien     aanwezig)." & vbCr & _
        "Het blad zal overnieuw worden opgebouwd aan de hand van de gegevens" & vbCr & _
        "op het blad 'Algemeen'." & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Wilt u doorgaan?", vbYesNo, "LET OP!")

If Answer = vbNo Then
MsgBox "Update van het OVB UTILITEITSBOUW-blad is beëindigd", vbCritical, "Update beëindigd"
Exit Sub
End If

'TER VOORKOMING VAN EPILEPTISCHE AANVAL
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
'OUDE BLAD VERWIJDEREN EN NIEUWE AANMAKEN
On Error GoTo Nosuchsheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Nosuchsheet:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Data").Visible = True

Sheets("DATA").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "OVB UTILITEITSBOUW"
ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False

'Kopieer kopregels
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A3:Q10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Range("A3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Waarschuwing linksboven
With Range("B1")
    .Value = "LET OP! Aanpassingen dienen te worden gemaakt in blad 'Algemeen'. Aanpassingen gemaakt     in dit blad gaan verloren bij de volgende update."
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = -16711932
    .Font.Size = 15
    End With


'Dubbele lijn
Rows("35:35").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .ColorIndex = 0
 '      .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

'Rijhoogten kopieren
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Rows("38:3000").Copy

Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Rows("35:2997").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Selection.Clear

'Ventilatietabel per kolom

'Ruimteeigenschappen tot 'hoogte'
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A38:G3000").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Range("A35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
    

'BOUWBESLUIT
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("U38:Y3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Range("H35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    

'AANWEZIG
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("AC38:AC3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Range("M35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


'VOLDOET?
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("AJ38:AJ3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Range("N35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'LIJNTJES BIJWERKEN
For r = 38 To 2997
    
    Range("Q" & r).Select
    
    If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
'               .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End If
    
Next r

'LEGE RIJEN VERWIJDEREN
Rows("30:34").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Rows("11:29").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


'Afdrukbereik instellen
For x = 1 To 3000
If Range("A" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
    Laatste = x
End If
Next

PA = "$A$3:$N$" & Laatste

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = PA
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 999
End With


ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

'TERUG NAAR BOVEN ETC
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A20").Select
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Select
Sheets("Data").Visible = False
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'AUTOFILTER
Columns("N").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("N1:N3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>-"

'BORDER
Sheets("OVB UTILITEITSBOUW").Range("A3:N9").Select
Selection.BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium

End Sub



Sub ovbwoningbouw()
'
'   Macro kopieert voor OVB WONINGBOUW relevante informatie naar een nieuw blad
'   RPR, 03/2012

Answer = MsgBox("Door deze handeling wordt het huidige blad ovb woningbouw verwijderd (indien aanwezig)."     & vbCr & _
        "Het blad zal overnieuw worden opgebouwd aan de hand van de gegevens" & vbCr & _
        "op het blad 'Algemeen'." & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Wilt u doorgaan?", vbYesNo, "LET OP!")

If Answer = vbNo Then
MsgBox "Update van het OVB UTILITEITSBOUW-blad is beëindigd", vbCritical, "Update beëindigd"
Exit Sub
End If

'TER VOORKOMING VAN EPILEPTISCHE AANVAL
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
'OUDE BLAD VERWIJDEREN EN NIEUWE AANMAKEN
On Error GoTo Nosuchsheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Nosuchsheet:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Data").Visible = True

Sheets("DATA").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "OVB WONINGBOUW"
ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False

'Kopieer kopregels
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A3:Q11").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("A3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A3:Q11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .ColorIndex = 0
 '      .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

'Waarschuwing linksboven
 With Range("B1")
    .Value = "LET OP! Aanpassingen dienen te worden gemaakt in blad 'Algemeen'. Aanpassingen gemaakt         in dit blad gaan verloren bij de volgende update."
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = -16711932
    .Font.Size = 15
End With

'Dubbele lijn
Rows("35:35").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .ColorIndex = 0
 '      .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

'Rijhoogten kopieren
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Rows("38:3000").Copy

Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Rows("35:2997").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Selection.Clear


'Ventilatietabel per kolom

'Ruimteeigenschappen tot 'oppervlakte'
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A38:F3000").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("A35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
    
'OPPERVLAKTE
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("N38:N3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("G35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    'CAPACITEIT ROOSTER
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("R38:R3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("H35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'BOUWBESLUIT (1/2)
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("U38:X3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("I35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    'BOUWBESLUIT (2/2)
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("Z38:Z3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("M35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    

'AANWEZIG
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("AC38:AE3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("N35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


'VOLDOET?
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("AJ38:AJ3000").Copy
   
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Range("Q35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'LIJNTJES BIJWERKEN
For r = 38 To 2997
    
    Range("P" & r).Select
    
    If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
'               .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End If
    
Next r

'LEGE RIJEN VERWIJDEREN
Rows("30:34").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Rows("11:29").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


'Afdrukbereik instellen
For x = 1 To 3000
If Range("A" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
    Laatste = x
End If
Next

PA = "$A$3:$Q$" & Laatste

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = PA
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 999
End With


ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

'TERUG NAAR BOVEN ETC
Sheets("Algemeen").Select
Range("A20").Select
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Select
Sheets("Data").Visible = False
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Rows("11").Hidden = False

'AUTOFILTER
Columns("Q").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("Q1:Q3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>-"

'BORDER
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Range("A3:N9").Select
Selection.BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium

'SAMENGEVOEGDE CELLEN SPLITSEN
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Range("D4:M9").Select
Selection.UnMerge

'FILTER NATUURLIJK
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("Algemeen").Range("R10")
If cell.Value = "nee" Then
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Columns("H").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheets("OVB WONINGBOUW").Columns("P").ColumnWidth = 0.1

End If
Next cell


End Sub

Sub printbereik()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = 1 To 3000
If Range("A" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
    Laatste = x
End If
Next

PA = "$A$3:$AK$" & Laatste

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = PA
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 999
End With


ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

End Sub


Sub copyUp()
Rows(Selection.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Sub copyDown()
Rows(Selection.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly how does it crash?  Do you get an error message, and is some part of the code highlighted?

Comment: It just crashes excel, no message nog code highlighted. Excel just stops.

Comment: There's nothing here which would respond to  a change in cell color, so it's difficult to see how just changing the color would trigger anything, let alone a complete crash.  You need to have someone look at the complete file.